# Apollo Client + NextJS memory leak, InMemoryCache

Tags: memory-leaks, next.js, server-side-rendering, apollo-client, in-memory-cache

Official Apollo and NextJS recommendations are about to create a new ApolloClient instance each time when the GraphQL request should be executed in case if SSR is used.

This shows good results by memory usage, memory grows for some amount and then resets with the garbage collector to the initial level.

The problem is that the initial memory usage level constantly grows and the debugger shows that leaking is caused by the "InMemoryCache" object that is attached to the ApolloClient instance as cache storage.

We tried to use the same "InMemoryCache" instance for the all new Apollo instances and tried to disable caching customizing policies in "defaultOptions", but the leak is still present.

Is it possible to turn off cache completely? Something like setting a "false" value for the "cache" option in ApolloClient initialization? Or maybe it's a known problem with a known solution and could be solved with customization of the "InMemoryCache"?

We tried numerous options, such as force cache garbage collection, eviction of the objects in the cache, etc., but nothing helped, the leak is still here.

Thank you!

Comment: We are also running into this exact issue, so far we have found no way around this. Have you found a solution?